# How does Entity Framework decide whether to reference an existing object or create a new one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Just for my curiosity (and future knowledge), how does Entity Framework 5 decide when to create a new object vs. referencing an existing one? I might have just been doing something wrong, but it seems that every now and then if I do something along the lines of:

```
using (TestDB db = new TestDB())
{
    var currParent = db.Parents.Where(p => p.Prop == passedProp).FirstOrDefault();
    if(currParent == null) {
         Parent newParent = new Parent();
         newParent.Prop = passedProp;
         currParent = newParent;
    }
    //maybe do something to currParent here
    var currThing = db.Things.Where(t => t.Prop == passedPropTwo).FirstOrDefault();
    currThing.Parent = currParent;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

EF will create a new Parent in the database, basically a copy of the currParent, and then set the Parent_ID value of currThing to that copy. Then, if I do it again (as in, if there's already two of those parents), it won't make a new Parent and instead link to the first one. I don't really understand this behavior, but after playing around with it for a while something like:

```
using (TestDB db = new TestDB())
{
    var currParent = db.Parents.Where(p => p.Prop == passedProp).FirstOrDefault();
    if(currParent == null) {
         Parent newParent = new Parent();
         newParent.Prop = passedProp;
         currParent = newParent;
    }
    //maybe do something to currParent here
    var currThing = db.Things.Where(t => t.Prop == passedPropTwo).FirstOrDefault();
    currThing.Parent = db.Parents.Where(p => p.ID == currParent.ID).First();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

seemed to fix the problem. Is there any reason this might happen that I should be aware of, or was there just something weird about the way I was doing it at the time? Sorry I can't be more specific about what the exact code was, I encountered this a while ago and fixed it with the above code so I didn't see any reason to ask about it. More generally, how does EF decide whether to reference an existing item instead of creating a new one? Just based on whether the ID is set or not? Thanks!

Comment: What is `newParent` in your code? Is it a newly instantiated `Parent`? Is it something out of the database? This is important.

Comment: newParent would be a newly created parent in the case that currParent is null (which, AFAIK, would mean that there isn't currently one in the database). I'll update the code in a second

Comment: To answer your question, "More generally, how does EF decide whether to reference an existing item instead of creating a new one?", this depends on where your object came from. Did it come from the database or did you instantiate it in memory? If your `db` object is "aware" of any entity, then upon calling `SaveChanges`, it will continue working with that same entity. However, it's not aware, then some other things matter. Generally, just setting `currThing.ParentID = currParent.ID` might be easiest in any case.

Comment: @Jaxidian thanks for the info, but what if, in the code-first model, I don't have a ParentID, instead I have a Parent object? or do you mean currThing.Parent.ID?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your question and answer it. I think this is what you're looking for. **Q:** How does EF know to reference an existing record or save a new record based on the posted code? **A:** A few things can affect this, depending on how you use EF. If you instantiate a new `Parent` object, it will have no ID. If it's a self-tracking entity, it will have an `Added` state. Also, your DBContext will have no knowledge of said entity. All of these things can influence if it's an insert or update. If, however, you select it from the database, then your DBContext is very aware of it.

Comment: Ultimately, when you select an entity from your database, your DBContext will keep (in memory) a/some collection/s of those entities. When you reference anything in that collection, that helps the DBContext know how to work with it. Other things can factor in with self-tracking entities or some other configurations of EF.

Comment: OK, I think that makes pretty good sense, thanks for clearing it up :) but is there a way to force it to become aware of that object? as in, if I create that parent object in one database context, and then pass it to another, how do I make that new context recognize it?

Comment: Check out `((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext` and look at `ApplyChanges`, `Attach`, and `Detach`. If it comes from another context, you'll first need to `Detach` it there and then use `ApplyChanges` or `Attach` to make the second context aware of it.

Comment: thanks for the help, but there doesn't seem to be an IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.ApplyChanges, at least not in my code, and .Attach wants an IEntityWithKey. should I just cast the Parent to an IEntityWithKey and Attach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your specific instance of your `DBContext` provided that specific instance of that entity to you, then it will know what record(s) in the database it represents and any changes you make to it will be proper to that(those) record(s) in the database. If you instantiate a new entity yourself, then you need to tell the `DBContext` what exactly that record is if it's anything but a new record that should be inserted into your database.

In the special scenario where you have multiple `DBContext` instances and one instance provides you this entity but you want to use another instance to work with and save the entity, then you have to use `((IObjectContextAdapter)firstDbContext).ObjectContext.Detach()` to orphan this entity and then use `((IObjectContextAdapter)secondDbContext).ObjectContext.Parents.Attach()` to attach it (or `ApplyChanges()` if you're also editing it - this will call `Attach` for you).

In some other special scenarios (your object has been serialized and/or you have self-tracking entities), some additional steps may be required, depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

---

To summarize, if your specific instance of your `DBContext` is "aware" of your specific instance of an entity, then it will work with it as if it is directly tied to that specific row in the database.

Comment: Did you figure out `ApplyChanges` and `Attach`? Another way might be this: `((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newParent, EntityState.Modified);`

Comment: thanks, what I ended up doing (I'll try it in a second) was db.Parents.Attach, which, judging by the description, seems to work the same way

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. My apologies for that error. I'll update the answer to reflect that. :)